# Couldn't download package from local repository for debian dists with nginx as a web server

Tags: nginx, package, debian, stretch, systemd-nspawn

I created a local repository for downloading stretch debian dist and I used nginx as a web server for this.
I downloaded all the files and dirs with `wget --no-parent --recursive http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch` and placed them in `/var/www/html`
but when I want to debootstrap my machine with this command `debootstrap --include=systemd-container,curl stretch /var/lib/machines/m1 http://[my machine ip]/debian` it gave me this error:

```
E: Couldn't download packages: libacl1 adduser libapparmor1 apt apt-utils libapt-inst2.0 ....
```

and this warning(s):

```
I: Retrieving xxd 2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u3
W: Couldn't download package xxd (ver 2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u3 arch amd64)
```

I don't understand! what is the problem?

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with systemd-nspawn; perhaps that tag should be removed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with your `wget` command, you downloaded all the repository metadata (under **/debian/dists/stretch**), but the actual packages are in a different location (under **/debian/pool**), so you weren't providing `debootstrap` with a complete repository.

The Debian Wiki has [a page that describes the 'Anatomy of a repository'](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository#Anatomy_of_a_repository). At the bottom of that page are some links to tools for working with repositories. Rather than using `wget` to copy an existing repo, I would recommend using software designed for mirroring and managing repos. I have successfully used [Aptly](https://www.aptly.info/) and [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) for this purpose.